# VSCode Formatting

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've been looking at how to fix this issue I'm having.

When I'm copying and pasting codes to the vscode.The initial code will be like this

```
dict = {
    "key_1"           : "x",
    "new_key"         : "y",
    "additional_key"  : "z" 
}
```

After pasting the code it shows like this

```
dict = {
    "key_1":"x",
    "new_key": "y",
    "additional_key":"z" 
}
```

How do I retain the same spacing as the initial code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If autoformat is enabled you can disable it, for python you can:

```
   "[python]": {
        "editor.formatOnSave": false
      },
```

or you can disable it globally,

```
"editor.formatOnSave": false,
```